# javascript error ( mentions is not defined )

Tags: node.js, discord.js

i have some error, can help me with it?
/home/discord/self/44/main.js:313

```
        user = mentions.members.first().user;
        ^

ReferenceError: mentions is not defined
    at Client.<anonymous> (/home/discord/self/44/main.js:313:9)
    at Client.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (/home/discord/self/44/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:31:14)
```

My code

```
      client.on('message', message => {
 let user1 = message.author;

      let user = message.author;
      if (message.mentions.members.first()) {
        user = mentions.members.first().user;
   }

     if (user !== user1) {
            if (message.content.includes(``)) {
               db.add(`${user.id}_cockie`, 2);
}}});
```

The main problem is that the error does not appear immediately, the bot works and processes commands / messages and after 50+- minutes it gives an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you should have to do is change `user = mentions.members.first().user` to
`user = message.mentions.members.first().user` By the way, you can just use `message.mentions.users.first()`